# How to calculate greater than or equal to in R using ppois?

Tags: r, poisson-distribution

I am trying to calculate P(x>=3) using R. What I wrote is the following;

```
ppois(3,4.5) #this returns 0.342296
```

the problem here is that the value is for (Px<=3). I know that including "lower = FALSE" will return P(X>3)

```
ppois(3,4.5,lower=FALSE) #This returns 0.657704 which is P(X>3)
```

What would I have to modify or include to return P(X>=3)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $ P(X \ge 3)$ is equivalent to $P(X > 2)$

We can then calculate the following probability as follow:
\begin{equation}
P(X > 2) =  1-P(X \le 2) = 0.8264
\end{equation}

We can then compute the desired probability using R:

```
# P(X>2)
ppois(2,4.5, FALSE)

#OR

# 1-P(X<=2)
1-ppois(2,4.5)
```

Output:

```
0.8264219
```

As a side note - RStudio is a R [Integrated Development Environment (IDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)

Comment: there is also the argument `lower.tail=FALSE` to `ppois` to save you the `1 - ` part.